# Getting a paragraph's text after a button press and passing it into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to speak the text that populates an HTML paragraph after a button is pressed. The library I am using for speech is [speak.js](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js), and so far, the simple demos I put together of my webpage speaking work. But, now I am pulling text off of the Internet after a button is pressed, and I would like this text to be spoken. I am having trouble figuring out how to pull the text into the HTML tag that has the `speak()` function.

```
<div class="container well" id="#wiki-body-container">
  <p id="wiki-body" onchange="speak('!!! TEXT GOES HERE !!!')"></p>
  <div id="audio"></div>
</div>
```

That is the HTML that I have. After a button is pressed, the paragraph with id `wiki-body` gets filled. This text what I want to use to populate the `speak()` function parameters.

How can I go about doing this?

**EDIT** (adding more code):

Here is the corresponding javascript I am using to populate the paragraph.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#wiki-body-container').hide();

  $('#search-button').click(function() {

    console.log($("#search").val().replace(" ", "_"));
    var searchTerm = $("#search").val().replace(" ", "_");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=' + searchTerm + '&callback=?',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
            var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
            var section = $('<p></p>').html(markup);

            // remove links as they will not work
            section.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
            // remove any references
            section.find('sup').remove();
            // remove cite error
            section.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
            // fill in html section with text
            $('#wiki-body-container').show();
            $('#wiki-body').html($(section).find('p'));
            speak(section); // Not able to call
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
          console.log(errorMessage)
        }
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the full HTML body.

```
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <a title="By English: Redrawn in SVG by Otourly (concept by Paullusmagnus)
Deutsch: Nachgezeichnet als Vektorgrafik von Otourly (Konezpt von Paullusmagnus). (Original image Image:Wikipedia-logo.png) [CC BY-SA 3.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons" href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia_svg_logo.svg"><img width="128" alt="Wikipedia svg logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Wikipedia_svg_logo.svg/1000px-Wikipedia_svg_logo.svg.png"></a>
  <p>Search Wikipedia by voice!</p>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Verbalize a query" required>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="search-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container well" id="#wiki-body-container">
  <p id="wiki-body"></p>
  <div id="audio"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: There is no onchange event for a paragraph. Add the speak to the end of the function that populates the P: `var someText = "Hello there"; document.getElementById("wiki-body").innerHTML=someText; speak(someText);`

Comment: The script that populates the paragraph and the script containing `speak()` are two different files. I would like to keep them that way. I see that I can't just import a javascript file into another. So how do I go about doing it?

Comment: You can attach the change() event only to <input>, <select> and <textarea> element and detect their value change. Not on other elements. You can use a MutationObserver to detect the changes.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: You can add more than one event handler to the same button. You can also rewrite the method you use to fill the paragraph. Without code we are just guessing. You can use setInterval to poll changes to the wikibody too

Comment: @mplungjan ok, I added my code! Thank your for your help thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want use a timer and check contents of `<p>` element, you can try [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) event:

```js
function changeText() {
  document.getElementById( 'wiki-body' ).innerText = document.getElementById( 'text' ).value
}

document.getElementById( 'wiki-body' ).addEventListener( 'DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  speak( this.innerText )
} )
```

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

```html
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/21843061212/speakclient.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text" value="Stack Overflow" />
<button type="button" onclick="changeText()">Add and Speak this text</button>

<p id="wiki-body"></p>
<div id="audio"></div>
```

**Note:** The `Speak` function of code snippet above can't execute. Because I couldn't find a free CDN for the `speak.js` script. Please execute the code on the client.

Comment: Feel free to comment me for anything.

Comment: I managed to get it to work after I put the JS code inside of `$(document).ready(function(){}`. I also changed the `onclick=""` in the HTML to a jQuery `$(...).click(function () {})`. Thank you for your help!!!! :)